# Android - prevent TextView to push out another element inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is the Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profileUserImage">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profileNickname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="No Nickname yet fdg d trdt rdrt tdr  td trd t"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnEditNickname"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

When `profileNickname` is getting too long, it pushes out `btnEditNickname` out of the LinearLayout and also overlays itself out of the Layout a bit before the text is getting wrapped. How can I get this annoying piece of c*** to wrap IN TIME, before ruining everything?? I'm getting sick of wasting hours of time for minor bs like that, I hate android!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this line to the TextView  `android:layout_weight="1"`

this is the final XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileNickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="No Nickname yet fdg d trdt rdrt tdr  td trd t"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnEditNickname"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profileNickname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="No Nickname yet fdg d trdt rdrt tdr  td trd t"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnEditNickname"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It'll give you the following result:

[image]

And don't forget to change the text color of the textView to that you want.

Comment: But when the text is short then the distance between text and icon is big, looks inacceptable